# Escaping Literal Quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, quotes, literals

How do I have two quoted phrases in javascript. This is the challenge: I am a double quoted string inside double quotes. I have this:

```
" I am a \"double quoted\" string inside "double quotes\".";
```

Comment: Escape the slashes. `\\\"`

Comment: You are only missing a ```\``` before the third `"`.

Comment: THis is what I have now and it still won't work: var myStr="I am a \"double quoted\"sting inside\"double quotes\".";// Change this line

Answer (score 1):

many things possible:

- use character code 34 (`String.fromCharCode(34)`) and concatanate
- double escape `"\\\""`
- use single quotes to quote double quotes `'"'`

probably more…

```js
var q=String.fromCharCode(34);
document.write(q+"quoted text, using a variable with String.fromCharCode(34)"+q+"<br>");
document.write("\"quoted text, single escaped quotes\"<br>");
document.write('"quoted text, quotes in single quotes"<br>');
document.write("you may use document.write(\"\\\"quoted text, single escaped quotes, displayed after double escaping\\\"\");<br>");
```

Comment: The single quote one didn't work. And how do I do double escape? This is what I have now: var myStr="I am a \"double quoted\"sting inside\"double quotes\".";// Change this line

Comment: added the interactive environment for you to try things out interactively. works for me. double escape is useful if there is something like eval or just you want to display the escaping character … it all depends what exactly you need it for. also added above now: using a variable (constant would work as well) that then easily can be concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Put it like this:

```
    alert("I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\".");
```

Comment: It still is the same problem. I really don't know what I am doing wrong now. this is what I have now: var myStr="I am a \"double quoted\"sting inside\"double quotes\".";// Change this line

Comment: This line works perfect. Just put myStr in the alert function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myStr = "I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\".";
```

Comment: You should at least explain your bit of code. Otherwise it is not an answer to just throw a code snippet at someone.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works well on the chrome browser but gives the error on the firefox browser.

```
var myStr = "I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\".";
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a freecodecamp question. that's the solution to the problem;

```
var myStr = "I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\".";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for anyone who may be confused with this example - while you need a \ before the quoted text, both at the start and end of the quoted section, the \ must always be in **front** of the quotation mark.

```
var myStr = "I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\".";  //This is correct

var myStr = "I am a \"double quoted"\ string inside \"double quotes"\."; //This is incorrect
```

Even though logically you are still surrounding the quoted text with \ marks, the second \ marks are not in the right place.  The correct solution may look wrong visually to anyone used to normal written quotations but it is necessary for javascript to function. The period after "double quotes" is part of the general string and not part of the second quoted section.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myStr="I am a \"double quoted\" string inside \"double quotes\"."; // Change this line
```

Comment: Please describe what you have done and why. Do not post code only